# How to access the location.params of the vaadin-router using lit?

Tags: javascript, lit, vaadin-router

According to the [documentation and demos](https://vaadin.github.io/router/vaadin-router/demo/#vaadin-router-route-parameters-demos) provided by Vaadin the route parameters should be bound to the location.params.
The examples provided are using polymer, and when I use LitElement the location.params is undefined.
Is there a trick other than to parse the url to extract the used url :parameter using JavaScript in combination with Lit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it by overriding the `onBeforeEnter` lifecycle callback:

```js
@customElement('example-view')
export class ExampleView extends LitElement implements BeforeEnterObserver {

  @state()
  private user = '';

  render() {
    return html`
      <h1>Hello, ${this.user ? this.user : 'stranger'}</h1>
    `;
  }

  async onBeforeEnter(location: RouterLocation) {
    this.user = location.params.user as string;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Your the answer however is based on TypeScript, but I'm looking for a JavaScript solution.

Comment: The same will work, just leave off the type definitions.